# How to convert mapinfo projection to proj4

Tags: map-projections, proj, mapinfo

I have some projection string exported by MapInfo, but I can't find way to convert them into proj4 string, could any one help me with this?

Here is the string:

"CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 104, "m", 29, 0, 1, 0, 0"

"CoordSys Earth Projection 8, 150, "m", 27, 0, 1, 0, 0"

Thanks,

Edgar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little googling:

```
+proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=29
+proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +lon_0=27
```

Link:

MapInfo projection and datum types: http://reference1.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/16.0/MapInfoProUserGuide.pdf

Notes:

1. WGS84 and Hartebeesthoek datums are coincident.
2. No need to specify default proj4 parameters.